# What does */13 do in a crontab?

Tags: cron

`*/n * * * *` in a crontab means run every `n` minutes, if `n` divides `60` evenly. What happens for other cases, like `*/13 * * * *`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

'*' is equivalent to the full range of possible values, in this case '0-59'

'/13' represents the "step size" or increment used to determine the next run, starting with the initial possible value.  (e.g. "Every 13 minutes starting at 0")

When the minutes get reset (59 to 0) it starts over.  So for example */13 will always run on 0 13 26 39 52.

Another example from the comments:

"Setting minutes as 3-59/5 will first fire at 3 and last fire at 58." -- [DZet](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/373987)

Comment: It is **not the remainder**, it is **step size**. Setting minutes as `3-59/5` will first fire at 3 and last fire at 58.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out.  This answer needs to be updated.  Do you think "step size" is the right term that everyone would understand?

Comment: I think step size should be fine